# Password checker in Python

Tags: python, beginner, python-2.x, validation

Using Python 2.7.12 I wrote a simple little script, `psk_validate.py`, that prompts the user for a potential password and checks if it has upper and lower-case characters, numbers, special characters, and that it has a length of at least 8 characters.

From what I understand one could use the regex library to write this much more efficiently, however, I have yet to learn about regex.

The program seems to work just fine, and with a program this small I think that not using regex is also just fine.

I'd like any and all feedback about this program. In particular, I'd like to know if a program written this simply could be used in real-world applications. I'd also like to know if there are any logical errors and/or bugs in the program.

```
from sys import exit

def check_upper(input):
    uppers = 0 
    upper_list = "A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z".split()
    for char in input:
        if char in upper_list:
            uppers += 1
    if uppers > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def check_lower(input):
    lowers = 0
    lower_list = "a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z".split()
    for char in input:
        if char in lower_list:
            lowers += 1
    if lowers > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def check_number(input):
    numbers = 0
    number_list = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0".split()
    for char in input:
        if char in number_list:
            numbers += 1
    if numbers > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def check_special(input):
    specials = 0
    special_list = "! @ $ % ^ & * ( ) _ - + = { } [ ] | \ , . > < / ? ~ ` \" ' : ;".split()
    for char in input:
        if char in special_list:
            specials += 1
    if specials > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def check_len(input):
    if len(input) >= 8:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def validate_password(input):
    check_dict = {
        'upper': check_upper(input),
        'lower': check_lower(input),
        'number': check_number(input),
        'special': check_special(input),
        'len' : check_len(input)
    }
    if check_upper(input) & check_lower(input) & check_number(input) & check_special(input) & check_len(input):
        return True
    else:
        print "Invalid password! Review below and change your password accordingly!"
        print
        if check_dict['upper'] == False:
            print "Password needs at least one upper-case character."
        if check_dict['lower'] == False:
            print "Password needs at least one lower-case character."
        if check_dict['number'] == False:
            print "Password needs at least one number."
        if check_dict['special'] == False:
            print "Password needs at least one special character."
        if check_dict['len'] == False:
            print "Password needs to be at least 8 characters in length." 
        print                  

while True:
    password = raw_input("Enter desired password: ")
    print 
    if validate_password(password):
        print "Password meets all requirements and may be used."
        print 
        print "Exiting program..."
        print
        exit(0)
```

Comment: Related: https://blogs.dropbox.com/tech/2012/04/zxcvbn-realistic-password-strength-estimation/

Answer (score 51, accepted):

### Concept

Obligatory XKCD comic, before I begin:

[image: XKCD Password Strength]

Enforcing password strength by requiring human-unfriendly characters is no longer considered good practice.  Nevertheless, I'll review the code as you have written it.

### "Obvious" simplifications

- Any code with the pattern `if bool_expr: return True; else: return False` should be written simply as `return bool_expr`.
- Strings are directly iterable; there is no need to convert them into a list first, using `.split()`.  In other words, the code would work the same if you just wrote:

  ```
  upper_list = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
  ```
- Better yet, you could just use [`string.ascii_uppercase`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ascii_uppercase).
- The `uppers += 1` counting loop could be written more expressively using the [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) built-in function.  Actually, in this case, since you only care whether `uppers > 0`, you could just use the [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function.

With those changes, your `check_upper()` function becomes a one-liner:

```
def contains_upper(s):
    return any(c in ascii_uppercase for c in s)
```

I've renamed `check_upper()` to `contains_upper()` to make it clear that the function returns `True` or `False`.  Also, avoid using variable names, like `input`, that coincide with names of built-in functions: it could cause trouble if you ever want to use [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input).

### Code duplication

Most of your `check_something()` functions are identical.  You should generalize, instead of duplicating the code.

```
from string import ascii_uppercase, ascii_lowercase, digits

def contains(required_chars, s):
    return any(c in required_chars for c in s)

def contains_upper(s):
    return contains(ascii_uppercase, s)

def contains_lower(s):
    return contains(ascii_lowercase, s)

def contains_digit(s):
    return contains(digits, s)

def contains_special(s):
    return contains(r"""!@$%^&*()_-+={}[]|\,.></?~`"':;""", s)

def long_enough(s):
    return len(s) >= 8
```

Note that I've used a [raw long string](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) to help deal with the need for backslashes in the punctuation string.

### validate_password()

The `check_dict` isn't doing anything for you.  You'd be no worse off with five boolean variables. You are also calling each validation function twice.

The `&` ([binary bitwise AND](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations)) operator is not quite appropriate here.  The `and` ([boolean AND](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations)) operator would be more appropriate. Even though the results appear identical, the execution differs: the logical `and` allows short-circuit evaluation.

Personally, I'd write it this way, gathering up a list of all of the failure messages:

```
def validate_password(password):
    VALIDATIONS = (
        (contains_upper, 'Password needs at least one upper-case character.'),
        (contains_lower, 'Password needs at least one lower-case character.'),
        (contains_digit, 'Password needs at least one number.'),
        (contains_special, 'Password needs at least one special character.'),
        (long_enough, 'Password needs to be at least 8 characters in length.'),
    )
    failures = [
        msg for validator, msg in VALIDATIONS if not validator(password)
    ]
    if not failures:
        return True
    else:
        print("Invalid password! Review below and change your password accordingly!\n")
        for msg in failures:
            print(msg)
        print('')
        return False
```

If the function returns `True` in one place, then it would be good practice to return `False` instead of `None` in the other branch, for consistency.

### Free-floating code

It is customary to put `if __name__ == '__main__':` around the statements in the module that are not inside a function.  That way, you could incorporate the functions into another program by doing `import psk_validate` without actually running this program.

Calling `sys.exit(0)` is rarely desirable or necessary, if you structure the code properly.  Here, all you needed was a `break`.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        password = raw_input("Enter desired password: ")
        print()
        if validate_password(password):
            print("Password meets all requirements and may be used.\n")
            print("Exiting program...\n")
            break
```

Comment: I think it's also obligatory to link [the relevant Security.SE question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/6095/46979), too. ;) +1

Comment: As a Python-enthusiast (not a pro), I had a hard time reading the `msg for validator, msg in VALIDATIONS...`line. As I parsed in my head as a list of two elements, one of which is `msg for validator` and the other one is `msg in VALIDATIONS...` (and it made no sense). Wouldn't it be more readable to just put parentheses around `validator, msg`, making the line `msg for (validator, msg) in VALIDATIONS...`?

Comment: This, XKCD Password generation challenge is also relevant: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/122756/xkcd-password-generator

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I personally haven't come across `for (a, b) in ...`, however if I did come across it then I'd go 'huh odd', which would break my train of thought.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire It's an example of unpacking. It's the same thing as `x, y = [1,2]`.  The loop version is *very* common with `dict` iteration as well: `for k, v in d.items()`. The assignment is not typically enclosed in parentheses. You might also be thrown by the fact it's a list comprehension, too. If you have trouble reading it, I'd actually recommend a *newline* after the `msg`, to separate the element evaluation from the loop iteration. Now that you know the pattern, though, you'll start recognizing it more easily.

Comment: @jpmc26 Thank you for the full explanation, though I know what it is: it's just that given the syntax, I didn't get it immediately. Hence the request to simply add parentheses. ;)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire As I said, the parentheses there are highly uncommon. I'd recommend a newline before the `for` to distinguish if you find it difficult to scan visually. That would draw attention to the `for`, making it very clear that you're reading the loop part of the comprehension. I do this often when the evaluation part is complex or the comprehension is long.

Answer (score 10):

- You can make `check_upper`, `check_lower`, etc all use one function, and so you want to make a function such as `check_contains(input, letters)`.
  Which can further be improved by:

  1. Returning early by using `return True` if `char in letters` is true.
  2. You can make this a comprehension.
  3. You can use `any` to achieve the same as (1) when using (2).

  And so I'd use:

  ```
  def check_contains(input, letters):
      return any(char in letters for char in input)
  ```
- I'd personally make `validate_password(input)` only return true or false, however to keep with what you're doing, I'll keep it so that it prints.
- Remove `sys.exit`, it's not intended to be used in programs. Instead use `break` to break out of the while loop.
- I'd use [`getpass`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html), rather than `raw_input` to get the users password. This is as it should turn echo off, and so won't display the users password, so others can shoulder serf for their password.
- Rather than manually writing out the strings, you can use [`strings`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html).

And so I'd change your code to:

```
from getpass import getpass
import string

def check_contains(input, letters):
    return any(char in letters for char in input)

def validate_password(input):
    valid = True
    if not check_contains(input, string.ascii_uppercase):
        valid = False
        print "Password needs at least one upper-case character."
    if not check_contains(input, string.ascii_lowercase):
        valid = False
        print "Password needs at least one lower-case character."
    if not check_contains(input, string.digits):
        valid = False
        print "Password needs at least one number."
    if not check_contains(input, string.punctuation + '#'):
        valid = False
        print "Password needs at least one special character."
    if len(input) < 8:
        valid = False
        print "Password needs to be at least 8 characters in length."
    return valid

while True:
    password = getpass("Enter desired password: ")
    if validate_password(password):
        print "Valid password"
        break
```

If you were to make your program follow [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), then `validate_password` shouldn't print. And so you may want to use the below instead. If printing your messages is *super* important for you, then that should be a separate function than validating if the password is correct.

```
from getpass import getpass
import string

def check_contains(input, letters):
    return any(char in letters for char in input)

def validate_password(input):
    return all([
        check_contains(input, string.ascii_uppercase),
        check_contains(input, string.ascii_lowercase),
        check_contains(input, string.digits),
        check_contains(input, string.punctuation + '#'),
        len(input) >= 8
    ])

while True:
    password = getpass("Enter desired password: ")
    if validate_password(password):
        print "Valid password"
        break
    else:
        print "invalid password"
```

Comment: You can replace hardcoded letters with `string.ascii_lowercase`, `string.ascii_uppercase` and numbers with `string.digits` as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

Comment: @grundic I edited to add that, I don't like having to remember it's 'lowercase', rather than 'lower' so I normally skip using it, ;P

Comment: Sure ;) And don't forget to `import string` :p

Comment: @grundic thanks, I legitimately forgot to add them, );

Comment: If many passwords need to be validated, you probably want to define global constants for the character classes as sets.

Comment: @Graipher Why as sets? IIRC strings are as good. But yeah, `punctuation` may be better as a constant, :)

Comment: Because `any(char in letters for char in input)` is \$\mathcal{O}(nm)\$ with `n = len(input)` and `m = len(letters)` in the worst case (none of the characters are in letters). By defining the constant as a set you pay that \$\mathcal{O}(m)\$ once and `check_contains` becomes \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$.

Comment: @Graipher Whilst I mistakenly thought char in string is \$O(1)\$. The worst case difference here, on my machine, is ~3.2e-08.

Comment: Yeah, since `len(letters)` is probably bounded by the ASCII table size in the worst case. Still, its a thing to keep in mind that `c in str` is not \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$.

Comment: @Graipher I definitely will, :) I don't know why I thought `c in str` was \$O(1)\$ when I knew `str in str` is \$O(n)\$, or is it \$O(nk)\$... I'll definitely keep it in mind, :)

Comment: Yeah, the size of the needle is also in there (which didn't matter here, because it was always a single character): https://stackoverflow.com/a/18139681/4042267